# Do we have experts here?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, community

Do we have experts here?

I mean do we have theorists, historicists, or researchers of Hinduism here? Some professionals like pundits/etc. who have better knowledge of Hinduism. For community growth, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 14):

I'm a [Sri Vaishnava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srivaishnava) (an [Iyengar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iyengar) to be precise), and I've done extensive reading in the Vedas, Puranas, Ramayana, and Mahabharata, as well as numerous scholarly books on Hinduism.

Comment: Very true - I have gone through many of your answers. which are well researched and erudite. Hence you may be termed a scholar of Hinduism.  Your questions, again well researched, are in a good part unanswered, showing your depth of knowledge and research. My salutations dear friend.

Answer (score 10):

I am initiated member of a Vaishnava sampradaya and study the Vaishnava literature regularly.

Comment: Which sampradayam, out of curiosity?  Are you a Sri Vaishnava?

Comment: Gaudiya Vaishnava. I have a good friend who is a Sri Vaishnava though. His name is Srinivasa dasa :)

Comment: Oh, I am a Sri Vaishnava.  What kind of Gaudiya Vaishnava are you?  Do you belong to a traditional Gaudiya Matham, or ISKCON?

Comment: ISKCON, but not sure why that doesn't count as a traditional Gaudiya Matha. Either way, happy to see a fellow Vaishnava here

Comment: Yeah, the feeling's mutual.

Comment: And by traditional I just meant older.

Answer (score 9):

I am a theorist. I am not an expert in Hinduism, but in the concept of God. From the study of our scriptures, practice and personal realization I have reinvented a theory that perfectly explains God and our existence.

Regarding tradition, I am also a *Vaishnava* and belong to the Jagannath cult of Odisha. Regarding practice, I follow both the path of knowledge and devotion.

Answer (score 5):

I am a follower of Sanatana Dharma. I would not call myself the follower of any Sampradaya. Born a Smartha (Shaivite Iyer) I have followed practices of both Sri Vaishnavism (Ramunajacharya teachings) and Advita school of Shankara. Fairly at home in Sanskrit, Hindi, Bengali and Tamil (apart from English) I can read Gujarati and understand Telugu though can't read) I have browsing through various sites learned a lot about Sanatana Dharma and to a certain extent Buddhism.

I cannot term myself an expert, but am definitely a scholar of Sanatana Dharma studying and studying the Vedas, Upanishads and Itihasa Puranas including the Ramayana and Mahabharata.

Most active members in this site are scholarly in their own way, who have done some research and study before either posting a question or an answer and they are helped by moderators and peers like Keshav Srinivasan, Rickcross, Fierce Lord, Destroyer, Swami Vishwananda, Swift Pushkar and others.

I personally feel , the site does not need any pundits or certified scholars, since trained professionals have their own drawbacks and limitations of thought process (This is applicable in all fields of knowledge - historic examples of Copernicus and Galileo immediately come to mind - who were persecuted for having a different and revolutionary viewpoint) and the free exchange of ideas and comments would be restricted.

Answer (score 4):

I am a normal person with a full time day job. I am reading about Hinduism as a philosophy with focus on the 6 Darshanas. In short I am not an expert.

> I mean do we have theorist, historicist or researcher of Hinduism
>   here?

If possible it'd be great if we could pass on this site's link to authentic gurus who are practitioners and have an online presence.

When you include theorist, historicist or researcher of Hinduism even Wendy Doniger types qualifies under this and I am afraid such people would only add further to misinterpretation of Hinduism.

So rather than a theorist we need a practitioner here.

Comment: "Suna: puccham iva vyartham pANDityam dharma varjitam" - just like a dog's tail is useless (it curls upwards hence doesn't cover private parts), so is a learned 'pundit' who doesn't follow or act according to what he learned in dharma.

Answer (score 3):

I am from sanatan dharma actually Brahman(Swami) like Keshav Srinivasan I've done extensive reading in the Vedas, Puranas, Ramayana, and Mahabharata, as well as Jain, Bodh and numerous scholarly books on Hinduism.

Answer (score 2):

I am a practicing Hindu - a Vaishnav to be more precise. I am well read and come from a technical background. As moderators of this forum - it is vital that we help shape the discourse on this forum in a meaningful way. I'd like the help of other editors to warn others when the post questions that would yield subjective or highly opioniated responses. To attract experts to this site - it is our duty to remind posters to stay away from personal attacks and focus on constructive debates. I'd like to see this project succeed.