# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The only question left to be discussed from [*The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) is that how do we promote our site?

As the site has entered Private Beta, I wish more and more users join the website which will not only help our site graduate but will also help out by asking fascinating questions, by answering interesting answers and thus helps in developing a rich source for Hinduism which will be useful for future visitors as well

So inorder to attract more users and visitors, we need some ideas to promote the website.

**Target Audience** :-

- Experts, particularly in major topics of Hinduism
- Enthusiasts who are looking for answers
- People of different religion who are eager to learn about Hinduism

There are various ways in which we can promote this website, like Blogs, Facebook, Twitter etc, but I would like to have some new ideas to promote the website in a different way, so post your ideas here, and upvote the best and interesting ones ....

Comment: [A Recipe to Promote your Site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

Answer (score 4):

Ask good questions/find good questions asked by others.

**Post links in your social circle:** facebook, twitter, etc: saying enlighten me.

Achieve:

1. get people to know about new platform.
2. get people involved in answering question
3. get people to follow question/forum for knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking if we could pass on the site to Hindu gurus and organizations and/or their disciples and members who have an online presence.

Something like Ramakrishna Mission and Arsha Vidya Gurukulam. If any of you know people from those, you could invite them to the site.

Comment: It would be nice if the site had a promotional flyer.  That would make it easy to advertise in places like Arsha Vidya Gurukulam.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need some [experts](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/277) here for increasing the percentage of answer as well as reliability and quality of site.

- If you know one who is expert in Hindu/Sanatan Dharma, then contact and invite him/her to this site.
- Inviting scholars from academic like "Vidya Pitha" and "Patha Shala" will be really helpful for this site I think.

You can do:

- Make aware of this community to existing SE users who are interested in Hinduism
- Contact users who are contributing or active in similar sites or blogs related to Hinduism and invite them or ask to contribute here.
- Twitter may also be a good network to promote.

Answer (score -1):

I have come across many authentic profiles of experts in the yahoo answers site.
 We can invite them to Hinduism stackexchange. It would help us in increasing "expert" users for our site.

It would eventually improve the quality.
Thats just my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

1. Start a page in Facebook and create an account in twitter.
2. Contact the admins of popular Facebook pages(Hinduism related only) like agniveer etc.
3. Share the link on every possible spiritual websites or Facebook pages.
4. Invite at least 10 friends of every member who joined in this website. This is the best way in my mind.

We're having 350+ members now, and if we invite at least 10 persons, the number will be 350 x 10 .