# How to deal with an answer which is basically "a blog owner's opinion/interpretetion"?

Tags: discussion, answers, post-quality

In recent times i found that one user is basically copy pasting posts from arbitrary/unknown blogs as answers.Many of his answers are like that with [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17295/4732) being a typical example.

How to deal with them(such answers)?

I don't think we should allow this to continue.What do the rules say on this matter?

For Instance this is a popular mantra:

> **Om namo bhagavate vAsudevAya
> shAntAkAram bhujaga shayanam padmanAbham suresham |
> vishwAdhAram gagana sadRsham meghavarNam shubhAngam ||**

The Devata of this Mantra is Vishnu and it is well known that this Mantra is for Vishnu.

Now, let's suppose I created a *xyz* blog and explained this in this way:

> The Devata of this mantra is Vishnu and it is one of the name of Shiva of Shiva Sahasranama. So, this Mantra is showing Vishnutwo of Sriman Mahadeva (Lord Shiva). 
>  
> **Om Namo=** Om represents Pranava who is Sriman Mahadeva himself and Namo here represents Lord is to be saluted. It is also seen in Namakam that Lord is to be saluted. 
>  
> **Bhagavate=** Lord Shiva is Bhagvan as proclaimed in many scriptures, Moreover Vedas only address Sriman Mahadeva as Bhagvan for eg. See Atharvasiras, Svetasvatara etc... 
>  
> **Vãsudevãya=** Vasudeva means who resides in everything. It is Lord Shiva who resides in everything through his AshtaMurty form. This is well described in Shatapatha and Kaushikti Brahmanas of Vedas.  
>  
> **Shãntãkãram=** who is peaceful. This denotes the very nature of Lord SadaShiva. 
>  
> **Bhujagasayanam=** It is Sriman Mahadeva who resides in serpent as Amsha in the form of Vishnu. 
>  
> **Padmanãbham=** This denotes presence of Sriman Mahadeva in Padmanabha temple. 
>  
> **Suresham =** Sriman Mahadeva is the God of God (Devadeva) it is well known. 
>  
> **Vishwãdharam =** Sriman Mahadeva in the form of Linga is the base of this world  
>  
> **Gaganasadrishm=** need not to be explained whose name is Digambara and Vyomakesha 
>  
> **Meghavarnam=** It represents Nila Lohita form of Shiva. We see both blue and red coloured cloud. 
>  
> **Subhangam=** Sriman Mahadeva has all bodily organ nice. It is also explained in Rudra Suktas of RigVeda and also  in Taittariya Aranyakas Mantras like 'Namo hiranyabahave hiranyavarnaya ...' 
>  
> **Lakshmikantam=** It is well known that MahaLakshmi is well known Shakti of Shiva denoting Rajas The other Shaktis beibg Mahakali and Mahasaraswati. One can check Varaha Purana and Shiva Purana for this. 
>  
> **Kamalanayanam=** Sriman Mahadeva has nice eyes like that of lotus 
>  
> **Yogividdhyranagamyam =** It is Shiva who is meditated by Yogi.  
>  
> **Vande Vishnum=** I salute the all pervasive one  
>  
>  **BhavaBhayaHaram:** Oh Bhava (Shiva) destroy our Bhaya. 
>  
> **SarvaLokaikaNãtham=** who is Lord of all worlds.
>
> Thus it is proved that 'Om Namo Bhagvate Vãsudevaya ... ' mantra is for Shiva and not for Vishnu.

Now from that same blog I copied that content and pasted here and answered questions. **Is this accepted in this Site?**

Comment: And moreover he is using sectarian blogs.

Comment: I think we shouldn't allow blogs at all. We can finalize/revise sources in revision of Valid sources.

Comment: @Rickross yes, that answer is blogger own intrepretation (imagination)... if we allow such answers also... then one can create any type of meaning through play of words...

Comment: @Tezz Yeah, & what great imagination..lolz..they are trying to prove -what u see in the morning sky blazing is not the Sun but the Moon..And yes such answers should not be allowed IMO too..

Comment: @Rickross Hi.. I have edited your question. Are you ok with it?.. you may also rollback if you do not like it...

Comment: @Tezz..Yeah no problem..but u are wasting ur time..u can't convince fanatics with gyana and logic..:P

Comment: It's completely against the  [se] rule to copy paste entire blogs as answers. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version)

Comment: @Tezz..btw ur analysis of the Vaishnava mantra is quite good in explaining why such sectarian unknown blogs shud be added to blocked lists (if there is some list of that kind ) on Hinduism SE..So u can add ur own answer if u want..

Comment: @Tezz You not only misinterpretated the shloka, you mispelled and you gave wrong meanings.

Comment: There are only blogs. There are no sectarian blogs. The interpretation given in the answer is the interpretation given few centuries ago. The answer you linked in the question should be seen as plagiarized question. The blog's interpretation is not own interpretation. Whereas the shloka given by Tezz is own interpretation. If you think rudra mantras interpretation is wrong, you shouldn't support the  misinterpretation of any other verses.

Comment: @SreeCharan What do u mean that there r no sectarian blogs?There r plenty of them..And what difference it makes if the interpretetions were imagined few centuries ago?They are all human imagaination/interpretation of Scripture to uphold their sectarian prejudices by human beings who lived in Kali..What Tezz has done is a befitting reply and a good exposure..

Comment: I mean while considering blogs, we shouldn't see which sect it is. If interpretations are human imaginations, what is the proof that your or most accepted  interpretation is right? We can't decide the meaning of shrutis. It depends on acceptance of the interpretation. I don't see a single person who says Parvatipati as Vishnu or Lakshmi kanta as Shiva.

Comment: @SreeCharan I mostly don't give my interpretations in my answers..I only quote directly from Scriptures...So i can't be accused of that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blogs which give Blog owner's interpretations shouldn't be allowed and answers which cite them as sources should be deleted.

For example, if a blog has exact Vedic Verses or Puranic verses, we can cite them in answers (without citing blog in answer) as these verses are not influenced by Blog author's intepretation. Similarly, if a blog has a particular Acharya's interpretation, we can quote them in answer without citing blog name or link. But we shouldn't allow blog owner's personal interpretations.

Coming to [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17295/4732) on Sri Rudram, this answer is completely copy pasted from a blog. But Blog owner's post explains how Sri Ranga Ramanuja and Sri Parashara Bhattar are interpreting each word of the Sri Rudram. However, it would be still better ,as said above, if OP cites exact quotes of Acharyas and can explain them in his own words.

So, i think it will be better if OP edits his answer mentioning exact commentaries and explain them instead of copy pasting them **completely** from some blog. Other users can help OP in getting exact commentaries of Acharyas.

Comment: Ok understood...

Comment: @Rickross We have given sometime to edit that answer. If even after that time it is not edited, it will be deleted. Meanwhile other users may help him in fetching exact commentaries.

Answer (score 4):

Simple Solution: **Use your voting power**!

---

If you don't use it enough, you've only yourself to blame in the long run! And when you downvote somebody's answer, don't forget to explain your reasons in comments. Always give feedback why you didn't like it.

Also, before voting, you can leave a comment and wait for the user to clarify his or her position i.e., delay your voting.

Anonymous downvoting has to be absolutely avoided irrespective of your personal beliefs.

> What do the rules say on this matter?

If you were thinking 'flag it for deletion', that's not allowed. As per current rules, anyone can write an answer citing a blog and it's valid for the site. That's why I proposed in my answer [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/790/2995) that blogs should not be used as a reference going forward. (That brings up another interesting question, are websites like [kamakoti.org](http://kamakoti.org/) and [hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Main_Page) blogs? Who will decide what's a 'blog' and what's an authentic 'website?')

But when the original blog owner writes the same answer here on Hinduism.SE he or she can choose to reference his blog or simply copy-paste it here. Some people might call it self-promotion, but I don't think of it like that. We should look at the content first and see if it answers the question before we jump to any conclusions. Also, take a look at this meta post: [Should a famous Hindu Swamiji, Guru, Indologist, Hindu book writer etc. were to join this forum](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677)

Here's some advice from [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48) excellent FAQ ([The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48)):

> tl;dr Please stop posting answers that are just copied out of Wikipedia or some random blog. If you see these things and they don't cite a source, flag (either "very low quality" or "other" and specify that the post is plagiarized) and downvote. **Even if they do cite a source, consider downvoting.**

Comment: Yeah good answer..regarding voting i was not asking about that..i wanted to know only about the rules..Also i am always in favor of commenting with downvotes..i think i also had a thread on that proposal here on meta..but it seems i had then very few supporters ..And moreover Kamakoti is the site associated with the Kanchi Peetham ..so it is among the most authentic Hindu websites..Hindupedia is also usually ok to quote from....