# can we have a clear statement what constitutes Pramana for this board?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

Only Hindu scripture is Pramana - that is reasonably clear.  But there are two caterpillars in the salad:

(1) The allegation of "Tamasic Puranas" which non-sectarian modern scholarship has rejected.  Are posters allowed to say evidence from some purana can be rejected a priori because it has been dubbed a "Tamasic Purana"?

(2) Alleging Puranic material to be "interpolations" without any scholarly argument.  Also using lack of citations in later works arbitrarily - saying that it is evidence of interpolation in some cases and giving convoluted explanations in other cases.

Comment: [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/277)

Comment: All the 18 puranas all the 18 upapuranas all the 18 smritis, all the 18 upasmritis Vedas, Upanishads, Tantras and so on are all valid references to cite from.. it does not matter what label a particular purana is carrying.. as regards interpolation claims..they can be ignored safely.. because no one knows (or can verify) the truth of them..

Answer (score 6):

Acceptable references are provided in multiple meta posts such as [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/3500),  [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597/3500) and [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/3500)

In short, this site allows quotes from direct Scriptures (Vedas, Agamas, Puranas without any commentary)  to Scholarly Works and  words of all Hindu Saints. But users *may* prefer answers with direct scriptures as references more than Scholarly works or words of saints as references for the same question.

**(1) The allegation of "Tamasic Puranas" which non-sectarian modern scholarship has rejected. Are posters allowed to say evidence from some purana can be rejected a priori because it has been dubbed a "Tamasic Purana"?**

Hinduism has many philosophies and many sects and this site allows beliefs and opinions of all Hindu sects. Concept of Tamasic Purana is rejected by some sects but it is believed to be genuine by some other sects. Every sect in Hinduism has different opinion on different issues. We have to respect all their beliefs. So, this site accepts opinions of all sects on "Concept of tamasic Puranas".

If you personally feel an answer is incorrect, downvote the answer. Stack Exchange sites (of which Hinduism SE belongs) are [Q&A sites](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour), not discussion forums. Even [comments should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) be used only for asking clarifications and suggest corrections on posts (questions and answers) and many comments become obsolete when they serve their purpose. If users want to discuss any topic, they may discuss in [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com).

**2) Alleging Puranic material to be "interpolations" without any scholarly argument. Also using lack of citations in later works arbitrarily - saying that it is evidence of interpolation in some cases and giving convoluted explanations in other cases.**

If Someone doesn't cite any sources for their answers , flag their answers for moderation attention. "Post notice" will be added and answers [will be deleted](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/827/3500) if users don't update sources. If  users give proper sources and if you personally feel their answers are not correct, you may downvote their answers. Don't use flags if you feel an answer is wrong. You should use [voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) for that purpose. You can become familiar with Stack Exchange by visiting [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931)  and also [FAQ specific](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/3500) to Hinduism SE.