# What are the sites which can be quoted on this site?

Tags: discussion

Which sites can be quoted on this site as sources of scriptures? I want to ask that while quoting excerpts from sacred texts which sites can be used as link as official texts and valid sources of scriptures?

Comment: Already discussed [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/5212). Any site which has authentic and relevant for your answer is fine.

Comment: Is gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in relevant to quote

Comment: Yes. If the site has Hinduism relevant material, why not? They provide translations and commentaries on Gita, Ramcharitmanas etc., what we should see whether the scripture and translation is related to Hinduism.  We also have a post on main site for helping in finding relevant sources. [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/5212)

Comment: @sarvabhouma thanks this question is more appropriate for my doubt. The answers are what I require