# Can posters cite hate websites in comments/answers?

Tags: support, sources-and-citations

In particular I am concerned about a site that spouts virulent hatred not only against Shiva but also against revered figures like Chandrasekara saraswati - the sankaracharya of Kanchi before the present one.  Although a Smarta, he had enormous following among vaishnavites.  To denigrate him is just gutter-level hate.  That site is full of erroneous facts and erroneous arguments and it is just ENDLESS hate.

Is there a policy not to allow citations of websites with hate content?

Comment: Blogs are [not considered](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/795/277) reliable source.

Comment: but they are allowed in comments

Comment: Why r u too much bothered about comments with links to that site? as told such websites are not allowed to cite in answers..@SK

Comment: @Pandya Correctoin. Blogs which are just blog owner's interpretation are not allowed. Else, they are allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/which-scriptures-sources-are-considered-valid)

Comment: We do no discuss about external websites on meta. We only discuss about Hinduism.SE that is main site. Remove the name of the website in the question. All websites are equally valid as sources if they are citing scriptural sources and not just random opinion of the author of the blog.

Comment: Note: One who wants to know the name of the site can see in edits.

Comment: citing that site allows posters to "outsource" their hate in comments.  All posters here with the same ideology as that site know about it, and have cited it, including the most prolific poster here.

Comment: You can always flag hate speech comment as rude/offensive.

Comment: can i flag urls pointing to hate websites @pandya  ? "Blogs which are just blog owner's interpretation are not allowed. Else, they are allowed" says Sarvabhouma.  this hate site misquotes scripture, cherry picks scripture and spews venom about Chandrasekara Saraswati - a revered figure.  It looks like sarvabhauma thinks that is peachy keen.